# Range of Numbers with Compounding Intervals

Tags: c#, math, gdi+

I need to compute the steps between a start and end in a range for the purpose of sizing fonts.

Given:

```
Start Value: 14.0,
End Value: 250.0,
Steps: 28

Resulting Values: 14.0, 15.5, 17.1, 18.9, ... 204.9, 226.3, 250.0
```

I calculated each value by adding `10.45%` to the previous value (based on trial and error), but how do I calculate this percentage?
Guessing there is some compounding interest type function that could be used here.
A formula or pseudo code is fine.

Ultimately, this will be a C#.

Comment: can you provide a code sample of what you are trying currently..?

Comment: Do you know the number of steps and need the percentage or do you know the percentage and need the steps?

Comment: I have the steps but need to compute the percent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
EndValue = StartValue * ( ( 1 + Percentage ) ^ NumberOfSteps )
```

is the basic formula you will need.

If you know the `NumberOfSteps` and you want the `Percentage`, a bit of algebra will get you the formula (pseudocode, `^` is the exponent operator):

```
EndValue / StartValue = ( 1 + Percentage ) ^ NumberOfSteps
(EndValue / StartValue) ^ (1 / NumberOfSteps) = 1 + Percentage
Percentage = ( (EndValue / StartValue) ^ (1 / NumberOfSteps) ) - 1
```

If you know `Percentage` and you want `NumberOfSteps`, you're better off with a loop

```
int NumberOfSteps = 0;
for(double i = StartValue; i < EndValue; i *= (1 + Percentage))
{
    ++NumberOfSteps;
}
```

Comment: Fantastic. Looks like "steps" should be "steps - 1" but that works.

Percentage = ( (EndValue / StartValue) ^ (1 / NumberOfSteps - 1) ) - 1

Answer (score 0):

Ce^(kt) is the Compounding intrest rate principal in math. Where C is the initial amount, e is the constant e= 2.71828.... its just like pi; k is the percentage and t is the time. If you want the percentage then work backwards with Ce^(kt) to get the K value.